# Android FQL Query error

Tags: android, facebook

I was successfully making an FQL query earlier today. Now when I try to make the same query I am getting the following message.

"error_code":190,"error_msg":"Error validating access token: The session has been invalidated because the user has changed the password."

I am making the query on my own account, and my password has not been changed. Any suggestions for why this may be happening?

Now I am getting this error.

"Error validating access token: Session does not match current stored session. This may be because the user changed the password since the time the session was created or Facebook has changed the session for security reasons."

Comment: Just log out and get yourself a new session token. Does that work? (You need to program for invalid session tokens anyway)

Comment: I tried logging out and then logged back in, didn't seem to work.

Comment: You've probably got a Javascript log in to use cookies, and php not to use cookies, or something like that. Some code might help diagnose?

Comment: This is on android, I'm using the Facebook SDK

Comment: Sorry - I'm following both tags (facebook + php) and didn't check which it was. "facebook.isSessionValid()" can return true even in the case above (it's in the docs). So if you get these errors, just call "authorize" again and handle the call backs. Have you tried authorize again, and then getting a new access token?

Comment: I haven't tried that, is there a reason I would have to reauthorize? My understanding was that an access token will not expire if in your onResume method you extend the token. Could my problem be that I am passing my token from one activity to another?

Comment: OK - added as the answer for future reference as that's going to be the problem. Has link to facebook documentation on it. Hope that sorts you out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on above comments, this will be this issue.

The Single Sign On (SSO) in Android allows a user to authorise your app, and once they have done that they will be signed straight in on subsequent visits if they've signed in to Facebook for any application on the phone/tablet.

The downside of this is that the SSO remembers the token and if the token becomes invalidated (by a user de-authorising the app or by them changing password or other details), it will try to use it anyway. You MUST check for those two errors specifically as "isSessionValid() will return true, even though it's not. If you catch one of those two errors, you call the authorize method again.

So, in your case, trap that error, and call authorize().

Documentation from Facebook:  http://developers.facebook.com/docs/mobile/android/build/#sso

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer, I added this to my code, should work fine now.